# AsyncTask вместо нескольких изображений сохраняет одно и то же изображение несколько раз

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Я из моих ресурсов выбираю несколько изображений, которые нужно сохранить на карту памяти, передаю их в наследник `AsyncTask`, но все эти изображения сохраняются идиентично.
Скажем, если я выбираю W,Z, то у меня сохраняются 2 Z.
В цикле я проверил, проблем не было, но асинхронно они по отдельности не сохраняются.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udvwc.png

Вот метод `onClick`

```
   public void onClick(View v) {

        String path = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
        myDir = new File(path);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        imageIndex = new ImageIndex();
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            if (checkBoxes[i].isChecked())
                new SaveImageTask(i).execute();
        }
```

А вот и класс-наследник `AsyncTask`

```
class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        int i;

        public SaveImageTask(int i) {
            this.i = i;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), images[i]);//Массив int вида R.drawable.x
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                fname = "Saved image " + (i + 1) + ".jpg";
                file = new File(myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Как можно исправить это?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `bitmap` полем класса `SaveImageTask`.

Comment: Ну да, у вас же 1 Bitmap на всё. Пока вы там с первой картинкой возитесь, bitmap уже ссылается на другую картинку.

Comment: Bitmap [] bitmaps = new Bitmap[26];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) bitmaps[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), images[i]);

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            if (checkBoxes[i].isChecked()) {
                index = i;
                new SaveImageTask(bitmaps[i], i).execute();
            }

А так сохраняет только одну последнюю картинку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе `doInBackground` создал цикл из выбранных изображений, который поочередно записывает файлы на карту.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        if (checkBoxes[i].isChecked()) {
            index.add(i);
            bitmap.add(bitmaps[i]);
        }
    if (bitmap.size() > 0)
        new SaveImageTask().execute();
```

Метод `doInBackground`

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    fname = "Saved image " + (index.get(i)) + ".jpg";
                    file = new File(myDir, fname);
                    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    MediaScannerConnection.
                            scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Оставил `AsyncTask` без параметров и полей.